# WCF service self signed certificate invalid on localhost in iis

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis, https, ssl-certificate

This is my first time creating a WCF service. I need to use HTTPS as I will be using MembershipBinding. The steps I have taken up to this point are:

1. Created a certificate authority using the makecert.exe application - from this I have created a server certificate and a client certificate.
2. Added the certificate authority to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities within Microsoft Management Console.
3. Added the client and server certificates to my personal certificates within Microsoft Management Console.
4. Created a https binding for the service in IIS using the server certificate.
5. Set the appropriate permissions for the app pool on the server certificate.
6. Defined the service certificate within the serviceBehaviours node in the web.config.

I am now testing the service using the WCF Test Client but I am getting the message:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from https://localhost:444/Service.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: https://localhost:444/Service.svc    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://localhost:444/Service.svc'.    Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'localhost:444'.    The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.    The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.HTTP GET Error    URI: https://localhost:444/Service.svc    There was an error downloading 'https://localhost:444/Service.svc'.    The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.    The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

The error suggests that there is an issue trusting the certificate but I have trusted the certificate authority used to create it so I don't know how to resolve it. The service worked fine when I was using http.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As your certificate is self-signed, you need to add a hack to your client call :

```
using (MyWCFServiceClient client = new MyWCFServiceClient())
{

#if DEBUG
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = TrustAllCertificatesCallback;
#endif

    client.MyCall();
}
```

And the definition for TrustAllCertificatesCallback :

```
internal static bool TrustAllCertificatesCallback(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
{
    bool isValid = true;
    // TODO logic to check your self-signed certifiacte

    return isValid;
}
```

The TrustAllCertificatesCallback  callback should be deactivated on your production environement.